# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I added `AndroidBootstrap` to a `libs` folder in my application root and set the `build.gradle` and `setting.gradle` to use this library but after i click sync project with `gradle` file it gives me this error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:D:/Android3/Project/backup/News/3/News/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

i check all `build.gradle` in project and i see that `build.gradle` in `AndroidBootstrap` project uses this lline

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
```

i change this line to :
 compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'

but this error do not disappear!

additionally, when i click open file in error line, it direct me to app level build.gradle witch do not contain `com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1` .
what is the problem ?
i'm waisting one day on this matter and cannot fix it.

Comment: This error is because you have different version of support library than included in library project. just change the version there with your version number or install it and sync.

Comment: where should i change the version?? i changed it in all my project but i think it can not sync

Comment: what is your support library version in sdk manager?

Comment: how can i compile it?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:x.x.x'
```

where `x.x.x` is the version of support library in your SDK manager.

Alternatively, you can install latest support library in your SDK manager and sync project.

Comment: i did that! but it do not affect

Comment: One of your dependencies may contain the support lib with different version than your sdk manager contains. That should be the reason why you are getting this error. You should check all build.gradle files. I do not know more reasons for this error.

Comment: when i remove this line: compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.0.1', the error disappear! but i do not know what's matter with this library?!

Comment: Try use release instead of debug.

Answer (score 1):

I used the android.support.annotations dependency in my Java library and also meet the error, then I simulate the butterknife-annotations' build gradle file (https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife-annotations/build.gradle) like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def logger = new com.android.build.gradle.internal.LoggerWrapper(project.logger)
def sdkHandler = new com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler(project, logger)
for (File file : sdkHandler.sdkLoader.repositories) {
  repositories.maven {
    url = file.toURI()
  }
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"

dependencies {
  compileOnly 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
}
```

It worked for me.